# Difference between two dates and show result in minutes per hour

Tags: python, datetime

I want to time total time between two dates and also want them to arrange per hour e.g.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d1 = "2020-02-04T05:50:00.000+0000"
>>> d2 = "2020-02-05T12:33:00.000+0000"

>>> d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1[:10]+' '+d1[11:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> print (d1)
2020-02-04 05:50:00
>>> d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2[:10]+' '+d2[11:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> print (d2)
2020-02-05 12:33:00

>> (d2 - d1).total_seconds() / 60
1843.0
```

It gives me total minutes between the dates, but what I actually want is minutes to be arranged per hour, for example,

10, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 33

In above the 5th hour has only 10 minutes, 6th has 60 minutes, ...., and 12th has 33 minutes.

Comment: How would you do it if you had no computer?

Comment: Yeah, it's getting too much complex to put that thought in a code. I am looking for a better simpler way. I can use conditions and loops for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for the minutes remaining in the first hour, the full hours that have passed between and the minutes passed in the last hour?

Given these steps, you could use:

```
import datetime
from math import floor

def list_minutes_per_h(dt1, dt2):
    first = 60 - d1.minute
    last = d2.minute
    full_h = floor((dt2 - dt1).seconds / 60 / 60)
    return [first] + [60] * full_h + [last]
```

Comment: Thanks David, with some changes I got my required results.